# Could not load an object as it is not available on this machine - Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Got an issue that is driving me mad. Every time a user accesses this file, he always gets the error messages: "Could not load an object as it is not available on this machine" & "Compile error in hidden module: MenuUtilities2" (or something along those lines)

I've looked around and checked if there is any files in the startup folders for excel, no luck.  I've also updated MSCOMCTL.OCX (This was suggested to me from another user), no luck there either.

It is written by an external company.  I've tried accessing the code for it, but it is password protected.

One other user has the issue, the person right beside him on the same version of Office 2010. It works on my PC, I have Office 2003, my colleague beside me has Office 2010 and the file works for him.  The file was received via email, it was then extracted from a Zip file and then opened from desktop. Windows 7 is the OS. I have also contacted the company that provided the file earlier today.

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks

Comment: We'll need way more information...  Does it work as expected for other users on that same machine?  Does it work for the user in question if they use a different machine?  Are they loading the file locally, or from a file share?  What version of Office is in question?  Which OS?  Have you contacted the company that provided it yet?

Comment: Is Office on both computers fully patched?

Comment: I've installed all Windows updates if that is what you mean?  If not, what can I do to fully patch it?

Comment: Windows Update for all Microsoft products (especially Office), including optional updates (except Bing etc.). One can suppose that the problem is a bug in Office 2003 that is fixed in 2010 - what is your take on that?

Comment: I have seen your [post on www.sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/microsoft-office/340270-could-not-load-object-not-available-machine-exce.html). I suppose that the suggested [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934179) didn't work for you? (Although it does support the hypothesis of a bug in Office 2003.)

Comment: Did you try to open it on the Office 2003 computer, safe it and open the newly safed file on the computer where it doesn't work? Or open it in Open Office and safe it as an Excel sheet again. And what if the user (for who it doesn't work) logs in on another computer (it is user-related or computer related)? In the latter case: consider re-installing/repairing Office. Please let us know how this works out.

Comment: I'll try all of these as soon as I get a chance to look at it tomorrow when I am with the user.

Comment: A year late, I know.  No fix was found.  The user contacted the external company and they arranged an alternative way of getting data.